# ArcGIS REST API Vehicle Routing Problem service does not accept HTTP POST method?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, http-post, vehicle-routing-problem

I am developing with ArcGIS REST API Vehicle Routing Problem service.

When I sent the request using HTTP GET method, I got the 414 error as the URI was too long. (I requested with 11 routes and 238 orders data.)

So I changed to POST method. Then I could get jobId.
However, when I used the jobId to request the solution with output parameters (`out_stops, out_routes, out_directions, out_unassigned_stops and solve_succeeded`), I got the errorMessage

> "Unable to complete operation"

Then I POSTed the request with less data that could be solved successfully using GET method before, but I still got the errorMessage `"Unable to complete operation"`.

Does it mean ArcGIS REST API Vehicle Routing Problem service does not accept HTTP POST method?

Here is my HTTP request URL:

> https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/submitJob?token=&orders={...}&order_pairs={...}&depots={...}&routes={...}&breaks=&time_units=Seconds&distance_units=Kilometers&uturn_policy=NO_UTURNS&default_date=1465394400000&time_window_factor=High&f=json

I use java Jersey2.x client to do the POST request.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/")
            .path("submitJob");
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("token", problem.getToken());
    form.param("orders", ordersRequestParameter);
    form.param("order_pairs", orderPairsRequestParameter);
    form.param("depots", depotsRequestParameter);
    form.param("routes", routesRequestParameter);
    form.param("breaks", breaksRequestParameter);
    form.param("time_units", "Seconds");
    form.param("distance_units", "Kilometers");
    form.param("uturn_policy", "NO_UTURNS");
    form.param("default_date", "1465394400000"); 
    form.param("time_window_factor", "High");
    form.param("f", "json"); 

    String jobIdResponse = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                                .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), String.class);
```

Comment: I think it's more likely that your POST encoding is incorrect. Try creating an echo proxy to display the actual content with flags, the compare your data content with a manual invocation of the serivce through the ArcGIS Manager interface.

Comment: That's true, @Vince . I checked it again and then found that the URL had been encoded twice. After I modified the request parameters, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is request parameter encoding incorrectness. After modification, I got the result successfully. So, you can use HTTP POST method to request ArcGIS REST API Vehicle Routing Problem service.